# jquery ui autocomplete with ajax with custom search not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jquery-ui

My json response is:

```
[{"value":"admin@admin.com"},{"value":"customer@customer.com"},{"value":"customer1@customer.com"},{"value":"provider@provider.com"}]
```

My jQuery:

```
$( "#email1" ).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
                 $.ajax({
                      url: "/useremail",
                      dataType: "json",
                      data: {
                           term: request.term
                      },
                      success: function (data) {
                          //response(data);
                          console.log(data);
                          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
                          response( $.grep( data, function( item ){
                               return matcher.test( item );
                          }));
                      }
                 });
        },
        minLength: 3
});
```

I cannot perform the custom search from my json data here is an example of document in which custom search is performed [jQuery-ui autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#example-1)

Basically my search would only show those email which match my input field. If i use only response(data) it shows all the result but does not show search.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
success: function (data) {
          //response(data);
          console.log(data);
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i");
          var d = $.grep( data, function(item) {
                return matcher.test( item.label || item.value || item );
          });
          response(d);
}
```

Comment: Your ans is perfect. but edit it you have put extra character i.e ')'  in var matcher variable